# osTicket add variables

Tags: php

I've been using osTicket right out of the box for a couple years now and it works wonderfully. I'm now using this system for a few of the medical clinics I support and I have added an additional field which requires the user to input the name of the clinic that they are at.

That is also working, but I cannot figure out how to get the clinic name included in the automated email that tells my staff that there is a new ticket open. I think I need to add a new base varialbe, but dont know how to do this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find line 32 of class.msgtpl.php (\include\class.msgtpl.php) stating this:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM '.EMAIL_TEMPLATE_TABLE.' WHERE tpl_id='.db_input($id);
```

Is there anything in the template that allows you to utilize the custom variables? If not, you can write in your own as it is probably just a simple preg_replace.

Answer (score 4):

In `include/class.ticket.php`, line 422

They are all in this function. Add accordingly to `$search` & `$replace`.

```
function replaceTemplateVars($text){
    global $cfg;

    $dept = $this->getDept();
    $staff= $this->getStaff();

    $search = array('/%id/','/%ticket/','/%email/','/%name/','/%subject/','/%topic/','/%phone/','/%status/','/%priority/',
                    '/%dept/','/%assigned_staff/','/%createdate/','/%duedate/','/%closedate/','/%url/');
    $replace = array($this->getId(),
                     $this->getExtId(),
                     $this->getEmail(),
                     $this->getName(),
                     $this->getSubject(),
                     $this->getHelpTopic(),
                     $this->getPhoneNumber(),
                     $this->getStatus(),
                     $this->getPriority(),
                     ($dept?$dept->getName():''),
                     ($staff?$staff->getName():''),
                     Format::db_daydatetime($this->getCreateDate()),
                     Format::db_daydatetime($this->getDueDate()),
                     Format::db_daydatetime($this->getCloseDate()),
                     $cfg->getBaseUrl());
    return preg_replace($search,$replace,$text);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! When answering a question with code, consider adding some more details (especially because this code seems to be copied from the source code rather than improved to answer the question already).